# Changing the Color of the Root View Controller in the UISplitView Controller

Tags: ipad

I want to change the Text color and the background color of the left hand side of the RootView Controller in my UISplitView controller.  This needs to happen in both orientations.

Comment: Is RootViewController a UINavigationController, UITableViewController, something else?  Is RootViewController designed in IB or in code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the text color:

```
// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
cell.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //Here you can use whatever color you want
return cell;
```

Comment: cell.textColor is deprecated so use cell.textLabel.textColor instead